# How to use a P5.js Sketch as the "Background" of my React App

Tags: reactjs, p5.js

I am currently working on an small react app and I was trying to figure out a way to render my p5.js sketch behind the react app and sort of be the backgroung of the root. Meaning the P5.js sketch has the full size of the browser and the app in rendered on top of that.

I already tried a couple of things with container divs but nothing worked. If anyone has experience with this I am happy about every kind of help.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the background to be stationary you can simply attach the background sketch to a div, size it to fill the window, and then set that div to have `position: fixed` and set `left`, `top`, `right`, and `bottom` all to `0`.

```js
// This is in place of an import statement
const { useRef, useState, useLayoutEffect } = React;

const SketchComp = props => {
  const containerRef = useRef();
  
  const Sketch = (p) => {
    p.setup = () => {
      p.createCanvas(p.windowWidth, p.windowHeight);
      p.stroke('paleturquoise');
      p.strokeWeight(9);
      p.frameRate(10);
      W = p.width;
    }

    // Just making it interesting: https://twitter.com/akira2768922/status/1460991841835249668?s=20
    let W, b, t=0, s=50, F=a=>p.map((b=t/60)%1,0,1,...[b,b+1].map(b=>p.noise(b|1,a)>.5?s:0))
    p.draw = () => {
      p.background('lightcyan');
      t += 5;
      let z;
      for(let x = 12; x--;)
        for(let y = 12; y--;)   
          (x+y)&1||p.rect(x*s,y*s,s,s,F(z=x+y*20),F(z+1),F(z+21),F(z+20))
    }
    
    p.windowResized = function() {
      p.resizeCanvas(p.windowWidth, p.windowHeight);
      W = p.width;
    }
  }

  useLayoutEffect(
    () => {
      // Make sure the p5.js canvas is a child of the component in the DOM
      let s = new p5(Sketch, containerRef.current);
      
      // Remove the sketch when the component is removed/replaced
      return () => s.remove();
    },
    // This empty list tells React that this effect never needs to get re-rendered
    []
  );

  return (
    <div className="sketch-container" ref={containerRef}></div>
  );
}

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <SketchComp />
      <h1>Example React App</h1>
      <p>This text should appear on top of the p5.js sketch</p>
      <p>{[...new Array(2000)].map(() => ". ")}</p>
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```css
.sketch-container {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: -1;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    opacity: 0.4;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.2/umd/react.development.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.2/umd/react-dom.development.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/p5@1.4.0/lib/p5.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="root"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

If you want to have the background scroll, you can use `position: absolute` and make the sketch's height match the content:

```js
// This is in place of an import statement
const { useRef, useState, useLayoutEffect } = React;

const SketchComp = props => {
  const containerRef = useRef();
  
  const Sketch = (p) => {
    p.setup = () => {
      p.createCanvas(p.windowWidth, containerRef.current.clientHeight);
      p.stroke('paleturquoise');
      p.strokeWeight(9);
      p.frameRate(10);
      W = p.width;
    }

    // Just making it interesting: https://twitter.com/akira2768922/status/1460991841835249668?s=20
    let W, b, t=0, s=50, F=a=>p.map((b=t/60)%1,0,1,...[b,b+1].map(b=>p.noise(b|1,a)>.5?s:0))
    p.draw = () => {
      p.background('lightcyan');
      t += 5;
      let z;
      for(let x = 12; x--;)
        for(let y = 12; y--;)   
          (x+y)&1||p.rect(x*s,y*s,s,s,F(z=x+y*20),F(z+1),F(z+21),F(z+20))
    }
    
    p.windowResized = function() {
      p.resizeCanvas(p.windowWidth, containerRef.current.clientHeight);
      W = p.width;
    }
  }

  useLayoutEffect(
    () => {
      // Make sure the p5.js canvas is a child of the component in the DOM
      let s = new p5(Sketch, containerRef.current);
      
      // Remove the sketch when the component is removed/replaced
      return () => s.remove();
    },
    // This empty list tells React that this effect never needs to get re-rendered
    []
  );

  return (
    <div className="sketch-container" ref={containerRef}></div>
  );
}

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <SketchComp />
      <h1>Example React App</h1>
      <p>This text should appear on top of the p5.js sketch</p>
      <p>{[...new Array(2000)].map(() => ". ")}</p>
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.App {
  position: relative;
  padding: 20px;
}

.sketch-container {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    opacity: 0.4;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.2/umd/react.development.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.2/umd/react-dom.development.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/p5@1.4.0/lib/p5.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="root"></div>
</body>

</html>
```